# Ajax post request with pure javascript, no jquery

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, fabrik

I'm using fabrik to develop some applications, it's great.
However I have the need to use ajax with it now, I know how to use it and I already have everything set up, but I need to fix the javascript code to do what I want, I want to use TCPDF with it, or basically just run a PHP function on demand.

This is my php code

```
public function doButton() {
    require_once JPATH_SITE . '/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $contenido = array();
    $contenido[] = '<html>';
    $contenido[] = 'Test';
    $contenido[] = '</html>';
    $pdf->writeHTML(implode($contenido), true, 0, true, 0);
    $pdf->lastPage();
    ob_end_clean();
    $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'D');
}
```

This is the javascript code I got and it works, but it's displaying an alert, I just want to run the function and send some input values through POST.

```
function doButton(el) {
    var url = "index.php?option=com_fabrik&format=raw&task=plugin.userAjax&method=doButton";
    new Request({url:url,
        onComplete: function(response) {
            if (response !== '') {
                alert(response);
            }
        }
    }).send();
}
```

I have a simple button that runs the javascript function doButton(this).

This may be dumb and simple, but I'm new to ajax and I can't find any similar code anywhere, seems to me like this ajax is using pure javascript, all examples I could find use jquery, which appears to not be supported and be completely different. I haven't found a single ajax with POST that doesn't use jquery.

[This is basically what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61424154/how-to-open-tcpdf-output-in-new-window-when-using-ajax), but in pure javascript.

Comment: JQuery does work with Joomla!, but you may need to declare it depending on the template you're using.

Comment: You can use a `fetch` or `XHR` request, depending on your browser requirements.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by jQuery is not suppoted. It's included in Joomla core, so you should not have a problem with jQuery ajax.

Depending on where you use it, you might need to add JHtml::_('jquery.framework');